# Title border panel with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How can I add a border with title to a panel using c# like this:
[see this pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsT9S.png)

Comment: Your question is way broad. Have you tried anything to solve your problem at least? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I'm new with c# andI did searched for a solution before asking here

Comment: You should show your effort, what you have done so far.

Comment: bro, I said I'm new and searched alot for a solution but I can't find a clear answer, show some mercy pls -_-

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Open the toolbox
2. Select the `GroupBox` control and drag it onto your form
3. Set the groupbox `Text` property to the desired caption
4. Drag other controls inside the groupbox

Answer (score 4):

What you looking for is called `GroupBox`

For more information about `GroupBox` refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox(v=vs.110).aspx).